# Value substitution in Ansible template

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-template

I am working on an Ansible playbook, where in a template I need to substitute a variable which is a list of dictionaries.

The task file is as follows:

```
vars:
locations:
  - context: "/rest"
    server: "http://locahost:8080;"
  - context: "/api"
    server: "http://localhost:9090;"
tasks:
- name: testing the template
  template:
    src: ./conf.j2
    dest: /tmp/test.conf
  with_items: '{{ locations }}'
```

I need to substitute the `locations` in the template. So the template is as follows:

```
{% for location in item %}
     location {{ location['context'] }}
     proxy_pass {{ location['server'] }}
{% endfor %}
```

I was expecting an output as follows:

```
location /rest
proxy_pass http://localhost:8080

location /api
proxy_pass htpp://localhost:9090
```

But i am having hard time in getting the substitution correct, can anybody help in pointing out where am I making the mistake.

The error I am getting is

```
failed: [127.0.0.1] (item={u'context': u'/rest', u'server': 
u'http://localhost:9090;'}) => {"failed": true, "item": {"context": 
"/rest", "server": "http://localhost:8080;"}, "msg": 
"AnsibleUndefinedVariable: 'context' is undefined"}
failed: [127.0.0.1] (item={u'context': u'/api', u'server': 
u'http://locahost:8080;'}) => {"failed": true, "item": {"context": 
"/api", "server": "http://locahost:9090;"}, "msg": 
"AnsibleUndefinedVariable: 'context' is undefined"}
```

Comment: Where exactly is the "substitution" you mentioned in the title and the first paragraph? I can't see any substitution here. Also, what result do you get and what happened to the semicolon in your expected result?

Comment: sorry for the confusion, the substitution is in the template. I was expecting the output as mentioned in the question, after tweaking the code many times I was not getting the correct output. Either I am getting error in execution or values are not getting substituted in the template

Comment: According to SO rules you should post the exact error message or description. In this form, the question should be closed.

Comment: I have updated the question, with the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this moment, because of `with_items`, you are passing the individual elements of the `locations` list, so in the first iteration, `item` becomes the following dictionary:

```
context: "/rest"
server: "http://locahost:8080;"
```

Then in the template you try to iterate this dictionary as a list (with `for`).

---

You need to decide if you want to loop outside of the template (create multiple files), or inside (create a single file).

Your case looks like the latter, so you don't need to use `with_items`:

```
- name: testing the template 
  template:
    src: ./conf.j2
    dest: /tmp/test.conf
```

With the template:

```
{% for location in locations %}
  location {{ location['context'] }}
  proxy_pass {{ location['server'] }}
{% endfor %}
```

<sup>You ignored my question about the missing semicolon at the end of your expected output, so deal with it yourself.</sup>